# { $e^{inx} : n \in Z$} forms an orthonormal basis of the hilbert space $L^2[0,2\pi]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am currently studying basics of Fourier analysis and I have read that { $e^{inx} : n \in Z$} forms an orthonormal basis of the hilbert space $L^2[0,2\pi]$. Now I am having a confusion regarding this. We know that a complete normed linear space cannot have a countable basis. Again $L^2[0,2\pi]$ is a complete normed linear space, the norm being induced form the inner product. Then how can it have a countable basis.

I am sure that I am missing on some details but I am not being able to figure it out at my own. It will be a great help if someone of you kindly help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your claim "A complete normed linear space cannot have a countable basis"? I don't think this is true.

Comment: The term "basis" is used in two slightly different ways, depending on whether or not you allow infinite combinations of basis elements. If you do, you have a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), and it is in this sense that $\exp(inx)$ forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2$

Comment: What is $L^2$ here? Complex functions on some real interval? Note that all $e^{inx}$ are $2\pi$-periodic and they are not elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (@Sten). Maybe if you take the space of functions on a circle $0\simeq 2\pi$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then *something like this* could be true in *some sense*.

Comment: @PeterFranek I took the space to be $L^2[0, 2\pi]$, but you're right, as written it's not clear

Comment: Which gets us roughly to the functions on the circle you started with. But the countable/uncountable distinction comes from whether you take V = span(basis) or V = cl(span(basis)). If you take the first, you can never have an uncountable space from a countable basis @PeterFranek

Comment: Sorry initially I failed to write my query accurately. I have corrected it now. n varies over integers, not natural numbers and the space I am considering is $L^2[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the content of [Riesz–Fischer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem).

As @Sten noted, we are talking about Schauder basis here (you allow infinite linear combination, not just finite ones). The uncountable "Hamel basis" (each function is a finite combination...) is much larger and impossible to write down explicitly.